# Value Dependency Analysis with Frama-C

Tags: c, dependencies, frama-c

At the end of the following program, the value of variable `x` depends on the set of variables `{x,y,z,c}`. Similarly, the value of variable `y` depends on the set of variables `{y,c}`.

```
int main(){
    int x = 100;
    int y = 50;
    int z = 20;
    int c = g();

    if (c){
        x += y + 1;
    }else{
        x += z + 1;
        y = y + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can I get this information from the Frama-c tool from the command line? If yes, I would highly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot obtain this result from one of the existing plugins of Frama-C on the `main` function you supplied. But, if you modify your code a bit, the plugin `From` will return exactly the information you want.

```
// test.c
int x = 100;
int y = 50;
int z = 20;

extern int c; // unknown value

int main(){

    if (c){
        x += y + 1;
    }else{
        x += z + 1;
        y = y + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> frama-c -deps test.c

```
[from] Done for function main
[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======
       These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function main:
  x FROM x; y; z; c
  y FROM y; c (and SELF)
  \result FROM \nothing
[from] ====== END OF DEPENDENCIES ======
```

The results for `x` are self-explaining. For `y`, you get the additional information that `y` may be unchanged since the beginning of the function, hence the `(and SELF)`.

The reason you get different results by initializing the variables out of `main` is due to the fact that the `-deps` analysis computes its results w.r.t. the state at the beginning of the function. In your `main`, since `x`, `y` and `z` are set to constant values, their final results depend only on `c`, which in turns only depends on what `g` reads to compute its result.

Comment: Is it possible to get this information at every program point? Since Frama-c is showing dependencies at the end of the function, to do so it must be computing dependencies at intermediate program points. Can I get dependencies at every program point?

Comment: This information is computed internally, but not stored -- because it is too big and difficult to output to the user. It's going to be difficult to extract. You can have a look at function `compute_using_cfg` inside file `src/from/from_compute.ml`. The result returned for the function `kf` is computed by `externalize ret_id kf Compute.before.(Fenv.to_ordered ret_id)`. You should be able to replace `ret_id` by another statement of the function `kf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `frama-c -pdg -pdg-print` options. It calls the PDG (*Program Dependence Graph*) plug-in. But you will need to decode the output which is a by cryptic.

You can also use the `-pdg-dot` option to get a more friendly representation using the `dot` graph format (from  [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/)).